# how do i print values in nested json array using node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

i have this json array.

```
[ { '0': { msg: 'helloworld1' } }, { '0': { msg: 'helloworld2' } } ]
```

and here I'm trying to console log the value of every msg by doing this.

```
jsonArray.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
    console.log(element['0']);
});
```

**output**

```
{ '0': { msg: 'helloworld1' } }
{ '0': { msg: 'helloworld2' } }


undefined
undefined
```

the question is, how do i print out the values of msg keys and why is it returning undefined?

Comment: Can't reproduce, works for me in my console using `jsonArray.forEach(x => console.log(x['0'].msg));`

Comment: Where are you getting the json array from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because the code shown works, it doesn't produce the "undefined" output claimed.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm getting it from MongoDB

Comment: @JaromandaX it gives me this error when i try your solution `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @SterlingArcher i don't understand why but your solution also returned `undefined`

Comment: oops, sorry, didn't see it was in a forEach - my bad

Comment: @JaromandaX no worries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to parse the data again as following:

```
var jsonArray = [ { '0': { msg: 'helloworld1' } }, { '0': { msg: 'helloworld2' } } ]
jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
jsonArray.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element['0'].msg);
});
```

This `JSON.stringify` should convert the data to string then `JSON.parse` will convert it to JS Object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***lodash*** for this.

```
var array = [ { '0': { msg: 'helloworld1' } }, { '0': { msg: 'helloworld2' } } ];

_.mapValues(array, function(array2) {
  _.mapValues(array2, function(array3){
    console.log(array3.msg)})
  })
```

This will return the value in 'msg' keys. Here is the lodash documentation. [loadh-map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues)

Answer (score 0):

You have no problem at all, apparently.

Check out: https://repl.it/Gh3i/0

If you click 'run' you get

```
helloworld1
helloworld2
```

The same applies if you use integers:

```
var jsonArray = [ { '0': { msg: 'helloworld1' } }, { '0': { msg: 'helloworld2' } } ];
jsonArray.forEach(function(element) {
   console.log(element[0].msg);
});
```

Comment: If there's no problem, why is this an answer? Close as "can't reproduce"

Comment: ok that's strange, it works in the link you put in your answer but it doesn't work in my case, it's always returning `undefined` in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the updated code attached below

```js
var jsonArray=[{"0":{"msg":"helloworld1"}},{"0":{"msg":"helloworld2"}}];



jsonArray.forEach(function(element) {
   console.log(element[0].msg);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but why would i use jQuery in node.js?

Comment: i have removed jquery please try it now :-)

Comment: please use double quotes in json

Comment: ie. please change [ { '0': { msg: 'helloworld1' } }, { '0': { msg: 'helloworld2' } } ] to [{"0":{"msg":"helloworld1"}},{"0":{"msg":"helloworld2"}}]

Comment: this is a json array that I'm getting from MongoDB so i can't change it, and i really ran the code many times but it still gives the same `undefined` output